# Why can't Xpath click the element?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am Trying to create a bot that can fill a cart with these beer bottles.  I really want to do this on a few different sites but for some reason i can only get it to open the page and click the first button, then it doesn't click the next button.  I tried ID, Name, pretty much anyway to identify the button but it won't click it.  I even tried sleep for 3 seconds.  I tried to see if it was in an Iframe but i don't think it is.  I'm out of ideas....  Link is https://www.sideprojectbrewing.com/shop?category=Beer+Release
I'm trying to access the add to cart element but does not seem to work
\
from Config import keys
from selenium import webdriver

```
def order(k): 
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\ezliv\Desktop\ShopBot1\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.get(k['product_url'])
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="thumb-biereblanche"]/div/div[1]/div/div/img').click()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="yui_3_17_2_1_1606181545139_755"]').click()
```

\\

Comment: I love getting a downvote with no reason.  I obviously tried to find the answer before i asked and i'm out of options.

Comment: Would help if you give the actual link. Mention which element you want there.I didn't down vote this. Down voter should add  a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following code:

```
driver.get(url_here)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

bottle = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="thumb-biereblanche"]/div/div[1]/div/div/img')))
bottle.click()

add_to_cart = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'sqs-add-to-cart-button-inner')))
add_to_cart.click()
```

Import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: This was a wait time issue then?  Does declaring these functions/variables help with the handling of the webdriver vs the way i tried to do it?  It appears to be working, but I just want to make sure I understand what i did wrong.

Comment: @Typicalusername yes right, your issue about wait. Then, for `add_to_cart` element, it seem like a dynamic id, so you can't find by id. `WebDriverWait` is more efficient than `sleep`, this is the waiting method that selenium provides. Hope this helps.